# How to change ace editor autocomplete result order

Tags: angular6, latex, ace-editor, tex

I have enabled autocomplete functionality for ace editor using angular 6. Both local keywords that are already added in the editor is suggested along with the snippets for the particular mode. Local keywords are showing first followed by the snippets list. I need to change the order of autocompletion list. I need to show snippets list before any local keywords. How can i achieve this, as there is not much support for ace in angular background.

Comment: if you include a MVCE, you'll get more help more easily

Answer (score 0):

Set score property on items passed to autocomplete https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/092b70c9e35f1b7aeb927925d89cb0264480d409/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L545

to modify the score assigned by the snippet completer you can do

```
snippetCompleter = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools").snippetCompleter
snippetCompleter.getCompletionsOrig =
     snippetCompleter.getCompletionsOrig || snippetCompleter.getCompletions;
snippetCompleter.getCompletions = function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    return this.getCompletionsOrig(editor, session, pos, prefix, function(err, completions) {
        if (completions) completions.forEach(function(c) { c.score = 1000 })
        callback(err, completions)
    })
}
```

or change https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/092b70c9e35f1b7aeb927925d89cb0264480d409/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L76 to do `score: snippetCompleter.snippetScore`, to allow configuring snippetScore simply by assigning a number to snippetCompleter.